# how to declare another spinner id in one class

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
public class StartCalvert extends Activity {

Spinner spnr,spnr2;
String[] numsys = {
        "Binary",
        "Decimal",
        "Octal",
        "Hexadecimal"
};

// this numsys how will i declare
String[] numsys2 = {
        "Binary",
        "Decimal",
        "Octal",
        "Hexadecimal"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.startcalvert);
    spnr2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spnr = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numsys);
   //declare here , like what above alike .
    spnr.setAdapter(adapter);
    spnr.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
```

Comment: do like how you did for `spnr` by having another adapter

Comment: What do you mean, "how to declare another spinner id..."? It looks like you are. What problem are you having, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Each Spinner has it's adapter has bind its Datasource with  view on it so , most likely you need to make one for each Spinner and any other Data Views

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate

```
  spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1 );
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2 );

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    SpinnerActivity.this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    numsys);
                            spinner1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            spinner1.setAdapter(adapterSpinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    SpinnerActivity.this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    numsys2);
                            spinner2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            spinner2.setAdapter(adapterSpinner2);

ItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new ItemSelectedListener();
                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);
                spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);
```

Declare inner class

```
class ItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long arg3) {

            LoggerGeneral.info("OnItemselected pressed");
            switch (parent.getId()) {

            case R.id.spinner1:


                break;

            case R.id.spinner2:

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    }
```